# How to animate the images which are stored in sqlite

Tags: iphone, sqlite, uiimageview

I have a UIImageView in which i want to display the series of images for the animation which are stored in sqlite . How can i do this?

in .h i have like..

```
         UIImageView *photosImgView;

       @property(nonatomic,retain)IBOutlet UIImageView *photosImgView;
```

in .m i have like..

```
  @synthesize photosImgView;

    - (void)viewDidLoad
        {
            [super viewDidLoad];

            PeopleTable *ppl = [[People alloc] init];

         photosImgView.animationImages=[NSArray arrayWithArray:ppl.photo]; //(problem is   in this line)

       photosImgView.animationDuration = 5;
      photosImgView.animationRepeatCount = 1;
      [photosImgView startAnimating];

     [self.view addSubview:photosImgView];
 }
```

Please help me..Thanks in advance...

Comment: what the mean by animation the image in sqlite..

Comment: i have some set of images in my sqlite table and column name is photos and i have photosImgView what i want is i want to display those images in this photosImgView one after the other.

Comment: so are you able to fetch images from database..?

Answer (score 0):

Use [FMDB](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb), that is easy...

and make a loop on your table (select)

```
NSMutableArray *imgs = [NSMutableArray array];
FMResultSet *s = [db executeQuery:@"SELECT * FROM myTable"];
while ([s next]) {
    [imgs addObject:[s stringForColumn:@"row"]];
}

photosImgView.animationImages=imgs;
```

done!